# Как спрятать radiobutton под img в стилях JS?

Tags: javascript, label, radiobutton

Есть две радио кнопки, которые должны быть спрятаны под изображения.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="energy" id="e"/><img src=".png" class="pic"/></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="energy" id="i"><img src=".png" class="pic"/></label>
```

в CSS я это делала таким образом:

```
label > input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
label > input + img {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 25px;
 }
```

Но теперь я хочу определять стили в JS.

```
const pic1 = document.querySelector('.pic')
function addStylesTo(node){
    node.style.padding = '25px'
    node.style.border='2px solid black'
  }
addStylesTo(pic1)
```

Вопрос: можно ли спрятать кнопку под изображение через функцию addStylesTo? Или как иначе на чистом JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> которые должны быть спрятаны под изображения.

Зачем? Просто сделайте радио-кнопки невидимыми.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('label > input[name=energy]').forEach(i => i.style.display = 'none');
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="energy" id="e" onclick="console.log(this.id)"/>
  <img src=".png" class="pic"/>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="energy" id="i" onclick="console.log(this.id)">
  <img src=".png" class="pic"/>
</label>
```